# In the constructor of an attribute class in c#, how can you tell what attribute target is being handled?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

If you have the following attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MyValidationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public MyValidationAttribute()
    {
        // If this is decorating a property, do this
        if (this.DecoratesProperty)  // Of course this is totally made up
        {
            Message = "This is decorating a property";
        }
        else
        {
            Message = "This is decorating a class";
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I just made up a (non-working) way to ask whether this decoration is on a property (versus a class).  But is there a way to do this that is real?

Of course thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your usage case? Since attribute by itself means nothing there has to be code that looks for it and that piece of code indeed knows if it is class/method/parameter...

Comment: The use case is a fairly complex system in place that has an existing infrastructure to deal with validation of WCF service request structures at the WCF server.  The validations are currently done through attributes that are attached to various properties in those request structures. There are numerous validations implemented this way, including one validation whose job it is to include a message in the WCF response that says this property is going to be deprecated.  My goal is to use the same infrastructure to be able to use a property to decorate the request structure itself as deprecated.

Comment: I still don't get why you need attribute have to know its target... In your sample you can `GetMessage(target)` instead of property (as code that picks attribute have to know if it is type or property at least to be able to find attribute)....

Answer (score -1):

Can you just tell the Attribute via constructor arguments, at the point it is declared?

e.g;

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TestAttribute(Type target)
    {
        if (target == typeof(object))
        {

        }
        else if (target == typeof(PropertyInfo))
        {

        }
    }
}

[TestAttribute(typeof(object))]
class SomeClass
{
    [TestAttribute(typeof(PropertyInfo))]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is certainly possible, although perhaps somewhat inelegant for my use case (see comment above).  It may be necessary, but I was hoping for either a more elegant solution.